# MySQL database not updating when form is submited

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

*EDITED* I am using HTML forms and PHP to upload data to a MySQL database. When I submit the information an image that i uploaded gets moved to a specific folder(the way i intended it to), but the data does not get uploaded to the data base. 
I added most of the code now, the site didn't allow me to add everything, I deleted some lines that in my opinion don't have anything to do with the problem at hand. so maybe you'll see the problem:

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<?php 

include("includes/db.php");

?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Inserting Product</title> 

<script src="//tinymce.cachefly.net/4.1/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script>
    tinymce.init({selector:'textarea'});
</script>
</head>

<body bgcolor="grey">


<form action="insert_product.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-
data"> 

    <table align="center" width="795" border="2" bgcolor="lime">

        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td align="right"><b>Product Category:</b></td>
            <td>
            <select name="product_cat" >
                <option>Select a Category</option>
                <?php 
    $get_cats = "select * from categories";

    $run_cats = mysqli_query($con, $get_cats);

    while ($row_cats=mysqli_fetch_array($run_cats)){

    $cat_id = $row_cats['cat_id']; 
    $cat_title = $row_cats['cat_title'];

    echo "<option value='$cat_id'>$cat_title</option>";
}
                ?>
            </select>
</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td align="right"><b>Product Publisher:</b></td>
        <td>            <select name="product_dev">
            <option>Select a Publisher</option>
            <?php
            $get_devs = "select * from developers";

            $run_devs = mysqli_query($con, $get_devs);

            while ($row_devs=mysqli_fetch_array($run_devs)){

            $dev_id = $row_devs['dev_id']; 
            $dev_title = $row_devs['dev_title'];

            echo "<option value='$dev_id'>$dev_title</option>";
}
            ?>
        </select>


            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td align="right"><b>Product Image:</b></td>
            <td><input type="file" name="product_image" /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td align="right"><b>Product Price:</b></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="product_price" required/></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td align="right"><b>Product Keywords:</b></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="product_keywords" size="50" 
required/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr align="center">
            <td colspan="7"><input type="submit" name="insert_post" 
value="Insert Product Now"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
</body> 
</html>
<?php 

if(isset($_POST['insert_post'])){

    $product_title = $_POST['product_title'];
    $product_cat= $_POST['product_cat'];
    $product_pub = $_POST['product_pub'];
    $product_dev = $_POST['product_dev'];
    $product_price = $_POST['product_price'];
    $product_desc = $_POST['product_desc'];
    $product_keywords = $_POST['product_keywords'];

    $product_image = $_FILES['product_image']['name'];
    $product_image_tmp = $_FILES['product_image']['tmp_name'];

    move_uploaded_file($product_image_tmp,"product_images/$product_image");

     $insert_product = "insert into products 
(product_cat,product_pub,product_dev,
product_title,product_price,product_desc,product_image,
product_keywords) values ('$product_cat','$product_pub','$product_dev',
'$product_title','$product_price','$product_desc',
'$product_image','$product_keywords')";

     $insert_pro = mysqli_query($con, $insert_product);

     if($insert_pro){

     echo "<script>alert('Product Has been inserted!')</script>";
     echo "<script>window.open('index.php?insert_product','_self')
</script>";

     }
}


?>
```

Comment: You do not have any sql queries or requests in here. Why expect a sql database to update when you are requesting nothing

Comment: We can't even see your code connecting to your mySql server. Please add the full code, if in case you ignored some parts.

Comment: @Tomm I think he does have a `SQL` query at `$insert_product` there are few problems there. First is his using his variables directly in the `SQL` very bad. You need to look in to using prepared statements because the current way people can do a SQL injection attack on you project. Also tell us do you get any errors check the console for any errors. Also verify that the connection to your database is happening.

Comment: @Sand good call, maybe he should include the insert_product file code aswell. And yeh this is major sql injection alert

Comment: use  `mysqli_error()`, do you get any errors? Also move uploaded file after successful data insert into database.

Comment: Try to do this two things 1) Print your error using mysqli_error($con) 2) Use  mysqli_real_escape_string() for the inputs in order to avoid potential security threat when using plain variables

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL.

Comment: @RintoGeorge a more comprehensive and safer solution would be to use parameterisation. escaping strings only works when all the variables are strings. Numeric values can still be vulnerable. In this specific case every field appears to be a string (unless that's the error!) but it's not the best solution in general.

Answer (score -3):

Your query seems fine.
Just verify your MySQLi connection.

It should be like:

```
$con = mysqli_connect("HOST", "USERNAME", "PASSWORD", "DATABASE_NAME");
```

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.

Comment: I have executed this query at my machine and it was working fine. 

Also, column's datatype might be not supporting the POSTED values.